# Where do the words for daughter, son, aunt, uncle, mother, father, cousin, nephew, niece come from?

Tags: etymology, kinship-terms

Please see Title. I'm not specifically referring to which language they came from... but if they come from something else. In other words, do they come from words with other meanings.

For example, do words for children come from a word that means "being that comes from one's loins" or something.

Comment: If you would be asking the origin of the four words you listed, the question would be acceptable. As the question is about an undefined number of words, it is not acceptable, IMO.

Comment: etc. removed. I thought that it would be clear that I was also including other ways of referring to family members.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I extracted the following from the online **[Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com)** Dictionary. It's interesting to see how all these words were transformed from Latin/Greek/Old High German/Middle English to the current English words.

**Note:** I know that this does not exactly answer your question, since you actually want to know if the words derived from words with other meanings. But I think that having the full list of originating languages here may be useful as other answers to your question may refer to it.

---

**DAUGHTER**

Middle English, *doughter*, from Old English *dohtor*; akin to Old High German *tohter* daughter, Greek *thygatēr*

First Known Use: before 12th century

---

**SON**

Middle English *sone*, from Old English *sunu*; akin to Old High German *sun* son, Greek *hyios*

First Known Use: before 12th century

---

**AUNT**

Middle English, from Old French *ante*, from Latin *amita*; akin to Old High German *amma* mother, nurse, Greek *amma* nurse

First Known Use: 14th century

---

**UNCLE**

Middle English, from Anglo-French, from Latin *avunculus* mother's brother; akin to Old English *ēam* uncle, Welsh *ewythr*, Latin *avus* grandfather

First Known Use: 14th century

---

**MOTHER**

Middle English *moder*, from Old English *mōdor*; akin to Old High German *muoter* mother, Latin *mater*, Greek *mētēr*, Sanskrit *mātṛ*

First Known Use: before 12th century

---

**FATHER**

Middle English *fader*, from Old English *fæder*; akin to Old High German *fater* father, Latin *pater*, Greek *patēr*

First Known Use: before 12th century

---

**COUSIN**

Middle English *cosin*, from Anglo-French *cusin*, *cosin*, from Latin *consobrinus*, from *com- + sobrinus* second cousin, from *soror* sister — more at [sister](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sister)

First Known Use: 13th century

---

**NEPHEW**

Middle English *nevew*, from Anglo-French *nevou*, *neveu*, from Latin *nepot*-, *nepos* grandson, nephew; akin to Old English *nefa* grandson, nephew, Sanskrit *napāt* grandson

First Known Use: 14th century

---

**NIECE**

Middle English *nece* granddaughter, niece, from Anglo-French *nece*, niece, from Late Latin *neptia*, from Latin *neptis*; akin to Latin *nepot*-, *nepos* grandson, nephew

First Known Use: 14th century

---

**Reference:**

http://www.merriam-webster.com

Comment: Yeah, I found some of those as well. Nephew/Niece is interesting. It looks like the root also is used in words like "nepotism" but that's just an observation.

Comment: It's not necessarily obvious above, but uncle in Latin is "little grandfather." The first-degree relations are pretty much straight from German roots.

Comment: Thanks moioci. I wonder how far back we can trace the meaning of words like mother and father, though. I would guess that these words have been around for so long that their original meaning is perhaps lost.

Comment: @Atømix probably mother was among the first words ever invented by the human race. Father may have come a little later. When did the cavemen realize that people had a father? :-)

Comment: I'm sure there are newer origins, though. Take Japanese/Chinese pictographs, for example. The character for mother is basically the same as for woman, except it's enlarged and has two strokes in the middle(pregnancy + nipples maybe?). 母=mother. 女=woman. I wonder if we can even trace these familial words back far enough to know if they have another noun/adjective/adverb as a root word.

Comment: In relation to (no pun intended!)your comment about the word mother probably having been around since the beginning of the human race, I believe that the "Muh.." vocalization is the first sound that most babies utter quite naturally, and so that is probably why it evolved as the word for mother in many languages.

Comment: Bit OT, but in Norwegian we got different word for male and female cousins.  Cousins are called "søskenbarn" - meaning "sibling-child(ren)".  A male cousin is called "fetter", and a female cousin (ironically enough) is called "kusine".  We also got "tremenning" (from 3) and "firmenning" (from 4) which I think would be the same as "cousin once and twice removed".

Comment: @Armstrongest According to the book "Chineasy" by Shaolan, the Chinese symbol for woman (the one you wrote above), traditionally symbolized a woman kneeling on the floor, to show obedience toward a man.

Answer (score 3):

[etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/) gives the origins and original-language meanings of most of these words (with the exception of the meaning of "daughter", which John Cowan describes in his answer).

In brief, focusing on meanings:

**Mother** meant "female parent" in Old English, and presumably something similar in its origin languages. It was

> "[b]ased ultimately on the baby-talk form *mā- (2); with the kinship
>   term suffix *-ter-"

**Father** derived similarly, but there is this additional note:

> Spelling with -th- (15c.) reflects widespread phonetic shift in Middle
>   English that turned -der to -ther in many words

**Son** is ultimately

> a derived noun from root *seue- (1) "to give birth"

and came to mean "son, descendant" in Old English.

**Cousin**:

> from Latin consobrinus "cousin," originally "mother's sister's son,"

**Nephew** in PIE meant

> "grandchild," and in a general sense, "male descendant other than son"

This became "sister's son, grandson, descendant," in Latin. **Niece** is a Late Latin feminine form of the Latin for "nephew".

**Aunt** has this:

> from Latin amita "paternal aunt" diminutive of *amma a baby-talk word for "mother"

And **uncle**:

> from Latin avunculus "mother's brother," literally "little
>   grandfather," diminutive of avus "grandfather," from PIE root *awo-
>   "grandfather, adult male relative other than one's father" [...] Replaced Old English eam (usually maternal; paternal uncle was fædera).

**Child**, similar to the example sentence in the question, relates to words meaning "womb"/"pregnant", coming to mean ""fetus, infant, unborn or newly born person" in Old English.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the origin of *daughter* in my mother language, Persian, and then I found this post and I thought it's worth sharing it. In ancient Persia the young female member of family, basically daughter, were called *doog taar* 'doog' meant milk and the 'taar' at the end makes it a noun meaning the person who milk the cows. This later changed in Persian to *dookh taar* and now in Farsi *dokh taar* - kh in Farsi is pronounce pretty much similar to German's *gh* and this word in German is pronounced very similar to Farsi.

Just in case someone needs a reference here is the link to Wiki, however, it's in Farsi language:
[This Link](https://fa.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%AF%D8%AE%D8%AA%D8%B1)

Answer (score 0):

*Mother, father, son, brother, sister* have pretty much always meant what they mean today.  It's clear that *mother* and *father* are ultimately derived from adult reinterpretation of babies' babbling things like /mamama/ and /dadada/; this is a worldwide process that gives us both informal and formal words for parents, and is constantly self-renewing.  *Brother* and *sister* may also be of this type.

*Daughter*, however, is ultimately 'milker', from the Proto-Indo-European root **dheugh-* 'press, touch, milk'; this change in meaning goes back to before PIE broke up into the various families.  All these words except *sister* have a common suffix, whose meaning is unknown; *sister* picked up its /t/ at the Proto-Germanic stage, and the other language families do not show /t/.

Comment: The ‘milker’ etymology is somewhat dubious. For one thing, the ‘daughter’ word does not appear to have _*-gʰ-_, but _*-gh₂-_, while the milking root has a clear _*-gʰ-_. This could be due to the fact that the kinship suffix is really _*h₂ter-_, rather than just _*-ter-_, but then we’re left with the unfortunate state of having to explain why a kinship suffix seems to also be an agent noun suffix (like _*-ter-_ is). ‘Father’ suffers from the same problem. ‘Sister’ (PIE _*su̯ésōr_) is almost certainly _*su̯e-_ ‘self, own’ + an archaic noun _*sor-_ ‘woman/girl’, i.e., ‘(our) own woman/girl’.

Comment: @curiousdannii  I wish you had not restored my answer, below, which I have now deleted as per the custom on this site.  When I thought it over, and did more research, I realized that my answer was falsely erudite and naïve and that it was beyond my capacity to improve it.  I am embarrassed by the answer, and  I  wish it could vanish into a black hole, never to be seen again, even in pale mauve.

Comment: A newer idea is that _ph2ter_ is actually from _*peh2-_</i> 'protect' plus _*-ter_, and that this was eventually reanalyzed to yield a new suffix_*-h2ter_

Answer (score -1):

I have the idea that Latin pater (father) might have been ○parantor (para.tor pa...tor pater), from the verb parare meaning prepare. So the idea might have been: He who was the preparing part.

No idea as to Greek thygater. I have the impression it is a word from neighbouring languages the Greeks have adopted and perhaps transformed.