# "th" in mother, father, brother— but not sister

Tags: etymology, nouns, kinship-terms

I was wondering why there is a "th" in *mother*, *father*, and *brother*, but not in ***sister***? Is the etymology of the word different?

Comment: The question seems open. But here's a related (broader) reddit thread about it: https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/2mfm7y/why_is_sister_so_different_to_other_family_members/

Comment: See also: [Where do the words for daughter, son, aunt, uncle, mother, father, cousin, nephew, niece come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1704/14073)

Comment: Who says that ["sister"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_9crI_zoqw)  doesn't have a "th" in it?  (At 0.48)

Comment: I suspect that the awkwardness of pronouncing "sisther" may be at least a part of it.  In the other family words, "th" is preceded by a vowel.

Comment: @HotLicks: what

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qx0jQL-hj1Q) is a little better -- at 2:27.

Comment: @HotLicks: 2:27 ... in a Wikipedia article ... I think I'll just leave you to your drugs :)

Comment: Rats!  Hosed the copy.  Edited it, so try again.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The short answer is yes; *sister* is formed a bit differently from the other words you list for as far back as we can trace. However, the evolution of these words over time has been a little complicated. Since the word "daughter" is also related, I'll discuss it as well.

As John Lawler says in his [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/296964/77227), all of these words are inherited from [Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) (and that's the furthest back that we can currently trace them with any certainty). The Proto-Indo-European (PIE) roots are reconstructed as follows, more or less (for the ones with less consensus on the details, I include several variant reconstructions separated by slashes):

*mātēr/meh<sub>2</sub>tēr/mah<sub>2</sub>tēr

*ph<sub>2</sub>tḗr

*bʰrātēr/bʰréh<sub>2</sub>tēr

*dʰugh<sub>2</sub>tḗr/dʰuktḗr

 *swésōr

You can see that at this point in time, the last root, for "sister," only has the final consonant in common with the others. On the other hand, the first four all seem to share the same ending (tēr).

However, PIE did have some kind of stress or pitch accent, and the placement of the stress (marked with an acute accent ´) was apparently different in the different words. This will be significant to later developments! I haven't marked the stress on the "mother" word because its descendants in different languages give conflicting information about the position of the stress. But in the ancestor of English, it seems the stress was on the final syllable (**mātḗr*).

English is descended from PIE through [Proto-Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language) (PG), which is defined as the common ancestor of all the Germanic languages. Here are the forms of the PG roots:

*mō**d**ēr

*fa**d**ēr

*brō**th**ēr

*duhtēr

*swes**t**ēr

The relevant sound-changes that get us from the PIE consonants to the PG ones are:

- [Grimm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_law): causes many consonants to change between PIE and Proto-Germanic. It's why PIE *p in the "father" word became PG *f, PIE *bh in the "brother" word became PG *b, and PIE *dh in the "daughter" word became PG *d. And by Grimm's law, PIE *t became PG *th, which explains the middle sound of a single word among these, *brother*.
- None of the other words here have *th in Proto-Germanic because Grimm's law had several regular exceptions. One common one is that PIE *t did not turn into *th when it came after certain other consonants in PG (namely, the fricatives); this is why the "daughter" word in Proto-Germanic has *ht rather than something like *hth. PIE *st was also preserved as PG *st. However, the "sister" word didn't actually have a *t in PIE, so it's not clear if  Grimm's law is relevant there. Another important regular exception is when consonants were subject to the following rule:
- [Verner's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verner%27s_law): the relevant part here is that when PIE *t came after an unstressed vowel in PIE (including a syllabic "laryngeal" like  h<sub>2</sub>/ə), it ended up as *d in Proto-Germanic. This applies to the "mother" and "father" words... we'll see how they got to their present English forms later.
- [Epenthetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis) insertion of *t to separate the PIE consonant cluster *sr (two other examples of this are PG **thimstra* "darkness" from PIE **thimsra*, and PG **straumaz* "stream" from PIE **srow-mó-s*; I took these from Piotr Gąsiorowski's paper [*The Germanic Reflexes of PIE* *-sr *in the context of Verner's Law*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vm2SugMy8C0C&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=stream%20epenthesis%20proto-indo-european&source=bl&ots=5Bl6VVeNqK&sig=YnttvumQLLgq_JbUqKxuccbQwC8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj059KA84zKAhVI6GMKHRaXB1MQ6AEITTAH#v=onepage&q=stream%20epenthesis%20proto-indo-european&f=false)). This process also occurred in the ancestor of the Slavic languages, Proto-Slavic. Gąsiorowski says that this sound change is "generally considered to be uncontroversial" (although he also argues that in some cases, Verner's Law regularly led to an alternative outcome of *r* or *rr*).

Note that Verner's Law means that the "brother" word actually has a different middle consonant from the "mother" and "father" words at this stage! It still does in standard High German (where we have *Mutter*, *Vater*, *Bru**d**er*, *Schwester*) and it did in Old English (where we have *mōdor, fæder, brōþor/brōðor, sweostor*).

But in Middle English, there was another sound change that turned the *d*-sound in the "mother" and "father" words into a *th*-sound. (Other words affected by this change include *gather, together, weather,* and *heather*; see this question and its answers for more information: [/ð/ → /d/ shift in English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141514))

And that's how we get to Modern English

mo**th**er

fa**th**er

brother

daughter

sister

Answer (score 32):

The reason there's a TH in the English words *father, mother,* and *brother*, but not in *sister,*
is that there was a **t* in the Proto-Indo-European roots for *[father](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=p%C9%99ter-), [mother](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=m%C4%81ter-),* and *[brother](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=bhr%C4%81ter-)*,
but **not** in the PIE root for *[sister](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=swesor-)*.

The series of [consonant changes recorded in Grimm's Law](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/GrimmsLawCognates.pdf) made those PIE **t* stops change into fricatives; 
these fricatives are the sounds spelled with TH in modern English.  Thus,

- PIE **bhrāter-* becomes ModE *brother* (PIE **bh* becomes ModE *b*, also by Grimm's Law)
- PIE **pəter-* becomes ModE *father* (PIE **p* becomes ModE *f*, also by Grimm's Law)
- PIE **māter-* becomes ModE *mother*

but

- PIE **swesor-* becomes ModE *sister* (the additional /t/ doesn't come from PIE)

Some family trees of other English words that come in various ways from PIE roots:

- **genə-* ['give birth to, be born; offspring'](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf)
- **dei-* ['shine'](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/dei.pdf)
- **penkʷe* ['five'](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/penkwe.pdf)
- **sed-* ['sit'](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sed.pdf).

Comment: +1 for explaining about PIE roots. I read that father, mother and brother has strong influences from Sanskrit (Indo) words - *pita*, *mata* and *bhaia* respectively.

Comment: Not strong influence from Sanskrit but rather parallel development from common predecessors. Sanskrit and English are distant cousins many times removed with very little impact on each other.

Comment: Where did the /t/ in sister come from if not from PIE?

Comment: @SophArch. Proto-Germanic (and also Proto-Slavic) inserted a /t/ into Indo-European *swesr- > Germanic *swestr-, presumably by analogy to the –tr ending of the inherited words for “father”, “mother” and “brother”.

Comment: And the /t/ was inserted in Germanic after Grimm's Law applied, since it didn't turn into a homorganic fricative.

Comment: @JohnLawler. That is not necessarily true. IE. /*st/ is not affected by Grimm's law.

Comment: @fdb: apparently it was probably epenthetic, as there is another example *thimstra < *thimsra "darkness": https://books.google.com/books?id=vm2SugMy8C0C&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=stream+epenthesis+proto-indo-european&source=bl&ots=5Bl6VVeNqK&sig=YnttvumQLLgq_JbUqKxuccbQwC8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj059KA84zKAhVI6GMKHRaXB1MQ6AEITTAH#v=onepage&q=stream%20epenthesis%20proto-indo-european&f=false

Comment: @sumelic. I think both are possible.

Comment: @fdb: but if there is a regular explanation, why bother to appeal to analogy? Anyway, if Gąsiorowski's idea in the linked paper is right (that epenthesis of -sr- to -str- in Germanic occurred after Verner's Law), it seems unlikely that analogy is a contributing factor, since after Verner's Law the "father" and "mother" words had *d rather than *t.

Answer (score 29):

I beg to differ with John Lawler’s answer. The proto-Germanic word for sister is *swestēr. So it is perfectly reasonable to ask why the /t/ in the ancestors of the words for “father”, “brother”, “mother” becomes th, while the /t/ in the Germanic ancestor of “sister” does not. The answer is that Grimm’s law affects freestanding /t/, but does not affect the /t/ in the cluster /st/.

Comment: Can you please explain Grimm's law some more and how exactly it causes this?

Comment: Since it is unclear when exactly the _t_ found its way into the word _sister_, a comparison with _daughter_ (not _daughther_) might illustrate the point better.

Answer (score -2):

I quote [Etymonline for 'mother (n.1)'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/mother#etymonline_v_18411):

> [b]ased ultimately on the baby-talk form *mā- (2); with the kinship term >suffix *-ter-

So (and while I am no expert) it appears that originally they had 'ter' rather than 'ther.'
In any case, then you'd have pater, moter, sister and broter. Then (from what everyone else is saying) Grimm's law would change the sounds of the other ones.

However, I do know (thanks to [http://www.lexilogos.com/english/latin_dictionary.htm's](http://www.lexilogos.com/english/latin_dictionary.htm%27s) Notre Dame link) that pater is the latin word for father in and of itself. Mater (not moter) was the latin word for mother, but the sounds are pretty similar. Sister and brother in latin weren't parallel to English, though. I can't really help there.