# suffix question

Tags: suffixes

I noticed that all these words have the same ending: mother, father, brother, other and another. Does anyone know what the suffix -ther means? Or is it a compound suffix: -th &-er?
Thank you

Comment: Given the general level here I will not chance an answer, but I think it is worth noting that in Swedish and German and even in French father/mother/brother/sister all end with a similar sound.

Comment: Strongly related: *[“th” in mother, father, brother— but not sister](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296946)* and *[Where do the words for daughter, son, aunt, uncle, mother, father, cousin, nephew, niece come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1704)*

Answer (score 2):

It is possible (but not certain) that *father*, *mother* and *brother* share a suffix: compare Latin *pater*, *mater* and *frater*. I don't know that anybody has a convincing answer for what this suffix may mean - or more to the point, what the roots without the suffix might mean.

*Other* and *another*, though, do share a suffix meaning "one of two", also seen in English in "either/neither", "whether", but also in Latin *alter* ("one or other of two") and *neuter* ("neither"), in Greek *heteros* ("different") and in Russian *vtoroy* ("second").